# DescribeFieldResult.getReferenceTo returns only one type in a specific scenario

Tags: apex, after-trigger, describefieldresult, polymorphism

I am seeing some strange behavior where `DescribeFieldResult.getReferenceTo` returns only one type for the `Lead.OwnerId` field in some cases when invoked in a trigger context.

The code below displays `OwnerId has 2 target types` as expected when run in a unit test or Execute Anonymous. But when it is run in a trigger it only finds one type: `User`, but not `Group`.

```
DescribeSObjectResult leadDesc = Lead.sObjectType.getDescribe();
Map<String, sObjectField> leadFields = leadDesc.fields.getMap();
sObjectField lookupField = leadFields.get('OwnerId');
DescribeFieldResult lfDesc = lookupField.getDescribe();
List<SObjectType> refObjs = lfDesc.getReferenceTo();
System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'OwnerId has ' + refObjs.size() + ' target types');
```

To make it even more curious this happens when the trigger is invoked as a result of a manual edit of a record, but not when the trigger is invoked as part of a unit test.

I'm stumped -- any thoughts would be very welcome...

**[Update]**
Further testing in a clean test org shows that this happens only:

- When the lead is updated from a list view or detail page

  - It works fine if the lead is updated from anonymous APEX, unit tests or batch APEX
- In an `insert` or `after update` trigger

  - `before update` triggers work OK
  - `after update` also works if the trigger also handles the `before update` event (even if it does nothing)

Specifically the following trigger fails the assertion:

```
trigger TestTrigger on Lead (after update) {
    List<SObjectType> refObjs = Lead.OwnerId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo();
    System.assertEquals(2, refObjs.size());
}
```

But it works fine like this:

```
trigger TestTrigger on Lead (before update, after update) {
    if (Trigger.isBefore) return;
    List<SObjectType> refObjs = Lead.OwnerId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo();
    System.assertEquals(2, refObjs.size());
}
```

The same code fails for `insert` triggers in any combination of `before` or `after`

Last observation: the `List<SObjectType>` returned by `DescribeFieldResult.getReferenceTo` is actually modifiable, and explicitly adding the `Group` object in the `before insert` allows the `after insert` to go through:

```
trigger TestTrigger on Lead (before insert, after insert) {
    List<SObjectType> refObjs = Lead.OwnerId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo();
    if (Trigger.isBefore && (refObjs.size()<2)) {
        refObjs.add(Group.sObjectType);
        refObjs = Lead.OwnerId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo();
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'OwnerId now has ' + refObjs.size() + ' target types');
    }
    System.assertEquals(2, refObjs.size());
}
```

It looks an awful lot like a defect to me -- but if there is some setting that would avoid the behavior I would be happy to know about it...

Comment: If you invoke the trigger on the lead that has queue as an Owner, than it will display another result in trigger class.

Are you sure you are retrieving sObject type from Lead (as a meta class) and not from the current lead_i sObject lead in the trigger?

Comment: @MariiaIllarionova thanks for the quick response, but I'm afraid I don't understand your question. The `DescribeSObjectResult` will (or at least should) be the same regardless of how it is obtained. And in any case I am sure that `Lead.sObjectType` refers to the Lead object, not an instance

Comment: I quess that happens in the trigger because actually you cannot assign the lead to a public group, only to queue, but queue is considered as User reference type in SF.

Comment: (1) does the running user have access to Lead queues in some use cases but not others (2) are classes and unit tests also at v46 (which is what exec anon is using at time of this OP)

Comment: Hi @cropredy not sure what you mean by 'access to Lead queues' in point 1)? Is there a specific permission you were thinking of? I'm using the same user in both scenarios.

And for point 2): yes, it's all v46